# How to integrate different domain in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-server

Currently using Sharepoint 2010 with domain A, i want add user in different domain B. Could you please help me how to do it.

Thanks,
Hieu

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to add with the old and trusted STSADM commands the info needed for the peoplepickers in SharePoint. By default SharePoint won't look in the other trusted domain for the users. There are a couple of blogs for it but it all comes down to what is explained here: [Multiple domains people picker](http://martinbruce.blogspot.be/2011/05/sharepoint-2010-multiple-domains-people.html?showComment=1307607931974)

I set up something on my test environment which has a separate domain than the one at the office. You can set up a two-way trust relationship between the 2 AD domains as is explained in a step-by-step guide here: [Setup domain trust for external domain](http://www.boostsolutions.com/blog/how-to-add-trust-domains-in-a-sharepoint-farm/)